# Web app works with VS2010 but not in IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I'm looking for explanation to the following behavior: I have small app that I run in a VS2010 installed on Win 2008 server. The source files are located in wwwroot folder. The application uses Microsoft.interop and Office Open xml to open a Office 2010 PowerPoint file. If I run the application using Visual Studio's built-in web server the application works fine. When I create an actual application on the server I get an error "PowerPoint could not open the file."

Both VS and IIS use the same application pool account which is a member of the local admin group. My account that I use to login to the server is also an admin account and so is the impersonation account. I using c:\temp for mytempDirectory setting in web.config to which all of these account have read/write/modify privileges. The presentation file is actually uploaded to a "files" folder within the app which at this point everyone have full permissions.

I'm guessing the issue is with permissions but I don't understand how? Has anyone experienced something like this?

Thanks.